# android webkit audio working on 4.1.2 and below but not above?

Tags: javascript, android, html5-audio

Hello there SO community,

I'm doing an app for android using html and js and the webview. The app plays sounds on button clicks (html). Thanks to you (SO people) i could make it work using this code : java =

```
    myJSInterface = new MyJSInterface(getApplicationContext());
    webview.addJavascriptInterface(myJSInterface, "Android");
```

public class MyJSInterface {

```
    Context mcontext;
    MediaPlayer mp;

    MyJSInterface(Context c) {
        mcontext = c;
    }
    public void MyAudioPlayer01(int audio) {
        /** play sound from the web page */
        if (issound) {
            Integer[] soundid = { null, null, R.raw.s01, R.raw.s02,
                    R.raw.s28, null, null, R.raw.xdhiboun, };

            if (soundid[audio] != null) {
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(mcontext, soundid[audio]);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        mp = null;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

I call the above code via js : js code =

```
    Android.MyAudioPlayer01(audio);
```

This works fine with android 4.1.2 but not above !

Could you suggest something (i have been searching whole day) ?

I also tried soundPool with no luck :-(

Is it something to do with js and the webview security updates ? do i need to add more permission for newer android version ? is mediaplayer obsolete ? ...

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem :

> Caution: If you've set your targetSdkVersion to 17 or higher, you must
>   add the @JavascriptInterface annotation to any method that you want
>   available to your JavaScript (the method must also be public). If you
>   do not provide the annotation, the method is not accessible by your
>   web page when running on Android 4.2 or higher.

Everything work fine now with mediaplayer and soundpool.

YOUPI :-)

Thank you all, peace.